# C++ State change not deleting old state?

Tags: c++, class, destructor

I'm working with Visual Studio and SDL to create a simple RPG game, however I noticed (when adding the music) that the music kept playing when I changed the gamestate, even though I stoped it in the destructor. If I stop the music right before changing the state though, the music stops (which made me realize that everytime i change the game state, the old state still remains, which I assume is using up a lot of memory (if i make the game big and change the state a lot).

My state classes are set up like this:

```
// Gamestate.h
#pragma once
// includes here

class GameState
{
public:
  virtual ~GameState() {}
  virtual void Update() {}
  virtual void HandleEvents() {}
  virtual void Logic() {}
  virtual void Draw(Graphics& gfx) {} // Graphics is my own class

  GameState* getCurrentState()
  {
    return currentState;
  }

protected:
  SDL_Renderer* renderer;
  GameState* currentState;
  Timer timer; // my own timer class
};

// GameStates.h; different than GameState.h
#pragma once
// includes here

class IntroGameState : public GameState
{
public:
  IntroGameState(SDL_Renderer* renderer, KeyboardClient& kbd);
  ~IntroGameState();
  void HandleEvents();
  void Logic();
  void Draw(Graphics& gfx);

private:
  Mix_Music* theme;
  // other variables defined here
};

// GameStates.cpp
IntroGameState::IntoroGameState(SDL_Renderer* renderer, KeyboardClient& kbd)
{
  GameState::renderer = renderer;
  currentState = this;
  timer.Start();

  theme = Mix_LoadMUS("theme.wav");
  Mis_PlayMusic(theme, 0);
}
IntroGameState::~IntroGameState()
{
  // This line does nothing (destructor not being called?)
  Mix_HaltMusic();

  delete theme;
  theme = NULL;
};
void IntroGameState::Logic()
{
  if (timer.ElapsedTime() >= 5) // if 5 seconds pass
  {
    // This line works
    Mix_HaltMusic();
    // I tried:
    // delete this;
    // delete currentState;
    // currentState = NULL; realized this was pointless when I just initialize it next

    currentState = new MovieSceneState(renderer, kbd);
}

// Game.cpp (where i actually change the state
Game::Game()
{
  // currentState here is defined within game.h
  currentState = new IntroGameState(renderer, kbd);
}
void Game::ComposeFrame()
{
  currentState->HandleEvents();
  ChangeState();
  currentState->Logic();
  currentState->Draw(gfx);
}
void ChangeState()
{
  GameState* s = currentState->GetCurrentState();
  currentState = s;
}
```

Comment: If you suspect that your IntroGameState class's constructor is not being called when you "delete currentState", then the first thing you should do is put a printf() (or similar function call with a reliably observable side effect) into your ~IntroGameState() method to determine whether it actually does get called or not.  Once you know that, you will be able to decide what to do next.

Comment: Do you intend for GameState::currentState to ever point to something other than the instance of GameState in which it is contained? (In IntroGameState's ctor you assign `currentState = this`). If not, why isn't `this` good enough?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner that's why I put the Mix_HaltMusic() in the destructor. If i leave out the Mix_HaltMusic in the other place, the music continues to play when the game state has changed, instead of stopping like I want it to. I also don't have music in the other states yet, but it still plays, unless I halt the music right before I change the gamestate.

Comment: @kfsone That's the only reason I have GameState::currentState. That way I can get the currentState from my Game class, and change the state there. When I tried [code]delete this[/code], i got a debug assertion failed. I placed that line of code before and after I changed the gameState.

Comment: Why don't you replace `GameState::currentState` - where you store what the state will be *next frame* - with a function `getNextState()` which you call at the top of the `ComposeFrame` function. It's job is either to return `this` or `new NewState()`. If it changes, then you delete the old currentState and set currentState to the return value you just got from NewState. I'd also encourage you to read up on `std::unique_ptr` and consider using it so you don't have to worry about these kinds of details. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: 'delete this' is almost always a bad idea, since you are deleting the object the the method is currently executing as part of, which means as soon as you do it, any access to member variables of the object the method is being called on becomes undefined behavior.  Don't do a 'delete this' unless you really know what you are doing (and try not to do it even then).  Note that you can avoid all of this pain by using smart pointers (e.g. unique_ptr or shared_ptr) instead of raw C++ pointers, then you never have to worry about calling delete at all.